# Only blue gradient is rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm using currently running a physics sim with a lot of different parts, and no matter what I do I am only able to render this. I have tried different solutions to similar problems and they have not worked. I have tried Eevee, Cycles, and Workbench, and all had the same result.

What it looks like when rendered
[image: screenshot 1 rendered]

What it looks like in the viewport
[image: screenshot 2 viewport]

Edit: My question was closed and was marked as a duplicate to a similar question. My question refers to a later edition of blender, and no solutions provided in the 'duplicate' question change the outcome in any way, shape, or form.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z6pi43znchwbts/Moai_statue.blend?dl=0

Comment: If you put a cube or other random object right behind the Moai head, does it appear? Wondering if its an issue with the Moai itself or the camera. My other main idea would be that theres an issue with the rigidbody cache

Comment: Hi Egdod, i know you are new here, but without seeing any of your settings we can just guess around. And since you are a beginner (what i am assuming) pls provide blend file so we don't have to ask lot of questions about your setup in the comments to help you. Thx.

Comment: Sorry! for clarification, here's the .blend file. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z6pi43znchwbts/Moai_statue.blend?dl=0
Also, I tried placing an object behind the moai, unsuccessfully. I even tried removing the custom material, exported from material maker 1.0.0, to no result.